# Posting a list of input in MVC4

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

after generating a question list to let user key in, i will like to post their input and save into database, but my view model can't get what user key in in the textfield. Any hint or guidance?

My viewmodel:

```
@model List<SurveyTool.Models.AnswerQuestionViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<br/>
<h2>Questions</h2>
<br/>



@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Survey_ID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].MaxChar)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Question)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                @switch (Model[i].Type)
                {
                    case "Info_Text":
                        {
                            <td></td>

                        }
                        break;

                    case "Single_Line":
                        {
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(m=>m[i].Answer, new { @maxlength = Model[i].MaxChar}) << textbox to input answer.
                            </td>
                        }
                        break;

                    case "Multiple_Line":
                        {
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m[i].Answer)
                            </td>
                        }
                        break;
                }

            </tr>
            }


    </table>

    <input value="Submit" type="submit" class="btn" />
}
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SURV_Answer_Submit(AnswerQuestionViewModel viewmodel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                  var query = from r in db.SURV_Question_Ext_Model.ToList()
                        join s in db.SURV_Question_Model
                        on r.Qext_Question_ID equals
                        s.Question_ID
                        where  s.Question_Survey_ID == viewmodel.Survey_ID && r.Qext_Language == viewmodel.Language
                        orderby s.Question_Position ascending
                        select new { r, s };

                foreach(var item in query)
                {
                    var answer = new SURV_Answer_Model();
                    answer.Answer_Qext_ID = item.r.Qext_Question_ID;
                    answer.Answer_Data = viewmodel.Answer; << can't get input!
                    db.SURV_Answer_Model.Add(answer);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }


                return RedirectToAction("SURV_Main_Index", "SURV_Main");
  }

            return View(viewmodel);
        }
```

Comment: Your model in the view is a collection, so your POST method needs to be `public ActionResult SURV_Answer_Submit(List<AnswerQuestionViewModel> viewmodel)`

Comment: your model is ``List<AnswerQuestionViewModel> `` while in action parameter is object of type ``AnswerQuestionViewModel``

Comment: Although your switch statement means that an input for the `Answer` property may not be included in view which means binding would fail - you must include an input (could be a hidden input)

Comment: Then if `ModelState` is invalid, it would fail again unless you call the database to get the `Type` property for each question, or include a hidden input for it.

Comment: hi @StephenMuecke, thanks for your feedback again. I tried for List<AnswerQuestionViewModel> but the viewmodel.Answer need change to viewmodel[i].Answer? Can you put some code guidance for me? Will be appreciate!

Comment: hi @StephenMuecke, thanks i had fixed it using for loop to get the position of answer input. Will value your comment for next phase.

Comment: @StephenMuecke could you please put your answer so i can marked it? Thanks! just mention the  List<AnswerQuestionViewModel>

Comment: Stephen Muecke Doesn't actually Put answers. He resolves questions in a Comments. It is good to know that you want to give him points for Good Answer. But for him Reputation almost means nothing. Like most of the users do when Stephen resolves their issue. You can always Answer Your own Question for Other users to view how he helps. Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You model in the view is defined as `@model List<AnswerQuestionViewModel>` which means the POST method signature need to be changed to

```
public ActionResult SURV_Answer_Submit(List<AnswerQuestionViewModel> viewmodel)
```

The use a loop to access each item in the model and save.

However there are also some other issues. The `DefaultModelBinder` required collection indexers to start at zero and be consecutive, but your `@switch (Model[i].Type)` statement means that a form control for `Answer` may not be rendered. To ensure binding does not fail when you submit, include a hidden input for `case "Info_Text":`.

You also do not include a form control for the `Type` property so if `ModelState` is invalid and you return the view, your code would fail (the value of `Type` will be `null`) so you either need to include a hidden input or call the database again to get the values before returning the view.